# gksudo keeps asking for my password when using a custom Unity launcher

Tags: 12.04, unity-2d, gksudo

I wrote a custom .desktop file that contains an Exec line

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
(...)
Exec=gksudo /my/path/to/bash_script.sh
(...)
```

This script launches some zenity calls.

Then I made this desktop file to appear in unity-2d launcher side bar.

My problem is every time I use this launcher shortcut it keeps asking for my password... While the expected behavior is to ask once, then remember for some time. **It was acting like that in gnome/Lucid so something has changed but what ?**

(I also tried '-k' option but doesn't change my problem)

If try that command line from a terminal (as my regular user)

```
gksudo /my/path/to/bash_script.sh
```

It works like expected (=same behavior as in Lucid): asks the password only on the first launch.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is the terminal environment which remembers the password for a certain amount of time.

For example, the command

```
gksudo nautilus
```

in the terminal will ask the password only once in a certain timeframe. While the same command in the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> launcher asks it every time.

Either way, if you want to run something as root, it is not that weird it will ask your password every time. That way you know you will be running the command as root.

Comment: You're right it is not that weird, but in Lucid, I had the same .desktop file and a different behavior: the password got remembered like any other app that needs administrative privileges (ie: synaptic...).

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely normal. In the terminal, you've always got the same "session", so it remembers the authentification, but that's not the same with a .desktop launcher.

I'd recommend you to just add a file to **/etc/sudoers.d** (name it my_script or something like that), so that you can always use your command without password (if your script doesn't accept arguments that should be safe) - but **do this at your own risk**:

Create a new file with following content

```
your_username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /my/path/to/bash_script.sh
```

When I tested it with gksu it worked directly afterwards, but if it doesn't, try logging in and out again or rebooting.

Comment: I don't want to disable password checking, I just wanna get the elevated privilege remembered like for any other app...ie synaptic etc. It was working great in Lucid but something has changed in Precise. It's not a big deal but I wanna understand what has changed :) Thanks anyway !